# runcommand (haskell) with unicode file paths

Tags: bash, haskell, unicode, normalization, unicode-normalization

I would like to run a bash command from Haskell which has unicode file paths.

Strings in Haskell  use \escapes e.g

`"beißen" -> "bei\223en"`

Bash seems to accept the following formats:

`$'bei\xC3\x9Fen.avi'` and `'beißen.avi'`

since `runCommand` from `System.Process` has the type

`runCommand :: String -> IO System.Process.Internals.ProcessHandle`

How do I encode the Haskell String to one of the formats that Bash accepts?

using Mac OSX 10.8.4 which has bash 3.2 .

EDIT

my problem seem to do with bash escaping

I am using `Text.ShellEscape` (http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/shell-escape/0.1.2/doc/html/Text-ShellEscape.html) to escape the characters that need be escaped for bash

e.g

```
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as B
import qualified Text.ShellEscape as Esc
let cmd = B.unpack $  Esc.bytes    $  Esc.bash . B.pack $ "beißen.txt"
```

which gives me `"$'bei\\xDFen.txt'"`

when running `runCommand $ "ls " ++  cmd`

it gives me 
`ls: bei�en.txt: No such file or directory`

It there a better way to escape strings for bash?

Comment: `runCommand "echo beißen >> beißen.txt && cat beißen.txt"` runs fine, what's the problem?

Comment: What are you trying to run and what errors are you getting?

Comment: I added some more info

Comment: Why escape the characters at all? Can't you just give the string "beißen.txt" as is to runCommand, without going through ByteString?

Comment: Because quite a lot of the string have single quote in them  e.g ab'c

Comment: @Bilal Does chaning the import from "import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as B" to "import qualified Data.ByteString.*UTF*8 as B" and replacing pack/unpack with fromString/toString help? (You may need to install the utf8-string package from hackage)

Comment: It works much better `B.unpack $  Esc.bytes $ Esc.bash $ B.fromString $ "beißen.txt"` gives me "$'bei\\xC3\\x9Fen.txt'".   but I have to use  `ls `echo -e $'bei\\xC3\\x9Fen.txt'`` since ls $'bei\\xC3\\x9Fen.txt'  gives me ls: bei\xC3\x9Fen.txt: No such file or directory.  I would accept your answer if post it.

Comment: Throughout the Haskellverse you generally want to use `bytestring` for bytes and `text` for text.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson: true, but at the inter-universal interface the picture is less rosy. `bash` wants bytes.

Comment: @n.m. But the question was about getting a `String` (for `runCommand`), not a byte vector - bash is just incidental.  Building the string as a String or as Text/unpack instead of Bytestring/unpack seems to make sense.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson: you need to escape the string first and `Text.ShellEscape` wants a bytestring (`bash` is a function in this package). This is probably fundamentally wrong in more than one way, but that's what we have at the moment.

Comment: @n.m. Ahh, huh.  I'm missing more context than I thought - thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Data.ByteString.Char8` is almost never the right choice if you want to deal with non-ASCII text. It will mangle your data. In your case you probably should use `Data.ByteString.UTF8` instead (provided you use a UTF-8 locale, which is the case for most modern desktop Unix-y OSes).

Example of `Data.ByteString.Char8` mangling data:

```
Prelude Data.ByteString.Char8> "été"
"e\769te\769"
Prelude Data.ByteString.Char8> unpack $ pack "été"
"e\SOHte\SOH"
Prelude Data.ByteString.Char8> Prelude.putStrLn "été"
été
Prelude Data.ByteString.Char8> Prelude.putStrLn $ unpack $ pack "été"
ete
```

Use `Data.ByteString.UTF8.toString` and not `Data.ByteString.Char8.unpack`.

These invocations

```
let s = toString $ bytes $ bash $ fromString "мама.sh"
runCommand s
runCommand $ "ls -l " ++ s
```

work for me from within ghci (`"мама.sh"` is a shell script with some Cyrillic characters in the name).

Of course if you escape the entire command it will also escape the white space and it will not work. Escape each word of the command individually.